# Mounted ISO is not ejecting in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mount, iso-image

I have Double click on RHEL ISO. It has been mounted. I wanted to copy the Packages. I am done with copy. I am facing problem when I eject the DVD aka ISO its not ejecting. Not giving error also.

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Sounds like there is still a file handle open on the mounted iso. This is not an entirely uncommon problem in Windows, unfortunately. Logging out and then back in should fix it, if not a restart almost certainly will. If a restart doesn't fix it, then it may be something else.

Comment: You don't mount an ISO by double clicking on it, but reboot the machine,

Comment: If I double click usually on ISO windows 10 it gets mounted. I have restarted system but its not going off.. Again I mounted another Ubuntu ISO. I am able to eject it successfully. But I am not able eject old RHEL ISO.

Comment: Can you identify the virtual device under `DVD/CD-Rom Drives` in Device Manager? You can disable or uninstall it from there if so.

Comment: I tried to uninstall in device manager. scan for hardware again it gets mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the ISO or Move the ISO to different location and restart your system. So that will dismount.

Something has gone bad in your OS i assume. Please Update and Upgrade to latest version make it up to date.

Usually when you mount ISO. Once you restart it will disappear automatically.Some registry entries is not getting clean off. And  make try one cleanup or repair registry with some good third party software. this may help you.

Once you done this Updates and registry cleanup.

If this work you can mount that ISO again. try it again.

Hope this will work

Answer (score 2):

Open PowerShell or cmd as the Administrator.
Run this command:  `mountvol DRIVELETTER: /d`

Examples:
- `mountvol F: /d`
- `mountvol G: /d`

Note: If the ISO gets mounted after restarting the PC, try renaming or moving the ISO.
Also, if you use a third-party tool (Ex: DAEMON Tools, Virtual CloneDrive, MagicISO, etc) to mount ISO, check its setting. You might have activated an automount or autostart option.

[image: Screenshot - DAEMON Tools Ultra]
<sup>Image Source: https://ultra.daemon-help.com</sup>

Further Reading
- https://ss64.com/nt/mountvol.html
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol